# How to run maven project on google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I follow this tutorial: http://software.danielwatrous.com/wordpress-plugin-licensing-wicket-on-google-app-engine/. I add google app engine library to this project and then I want to check google app engine on. But when I do this eclipse has this problem:

```
The App Engine SDK '/home/hudi/program/git/tournamenSystem/tournament-system/
tournament-system-web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.1.jar'
on the project's build path is not valid (SDK location '/home/hudi/program/git/
tournamenSystem/tournament-system/tournament-system-web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/
lib/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.1.jar' is not a directory)
```

I dont understand it. Jar isnt directory so why it want to some directory ? When I want use quick fix then I can just use another SDK. I try to use older version 1.6... but still same problem. How I can fix it ? Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible solution is that, you should add appengine through app engine settings in eclipse and make sure that the sdk added by appengine setting appear before the one mentioned (i.e. /home/hudi/program/git/tournamenSystem/tournament-system/tournament-system-web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.1.jar) in your build path. In this way your application would refer the appengine sdk from google plugin and not for the path which is giving error.

I had same issue where I was getting error for the sdk jar included from maven dependency.Hope it will help.

[image: Goole App Engine Setting]

[image: Build path order]

Comment: Indeed I can confirm that moving all System library Dependencies to the bottom solved the same error for me, which are: GWT SDK,
Web App Libs, EAR Libs, JRE, Maven. Just move all of them to the bottom and the error is gone.

Comment: @membersound great to hear that :)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at the [Maven GAE Plugin](https://github.com/maven-gae-plugin/maven-gae-plugin)
This plugin has goals to run, debug, deploy, etc. your GAE application.

Answer (score 1):

On my computer with Ubuntu 12.04 and Eclipse Juno SR1 
I just move all maven dependencies to the button of the list of Java build path.

For open Java build path window right click on the project 
- preferences 
- Java build path 
- Order and Export 
- select all row with M2_REPO(or some thing else) and press button "Bottom" 
- Refresh project. 
This need help.

Thank you!