# appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.6.jar is not a directory

Tags: java, maven, gwt, objectify

I just started using Maven in my projects.

I converted an old project to a Maven project and at first everything worked fine. But now I have a problem.

When I try to run the application (is a GWT application that uses Objectify) I get the following error:

SDK location '/Users/abelbarbosa/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk/1.7.6/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.6.jar' is not a directory

I know that it isn't a directory but i don't think it was supposed to be. I don't know how to correct this.

Is there anything wrong with my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>WebConFuturo</groupId>
  <artifactId>WebConFuturo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <organization>
    <name>OhApp!</name>
    <url>www.ohapp.pt</url>
  </organization>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
      <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
      <version>4.0b3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.web.bindery</groupId>
      <artifactId>requestfactory</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.1-rc1</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>/Users/abelbarbosa/Documents/workspace/WebConFuturo/src</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>/Users/abelbarbosa/Documents/workspace/WebConFuturo/src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>/Users/abelbarbosa/Documents/workspace/WebConFuturo/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>/Users/abelbarbosa/Documents/workspace/WebConFuturo/target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>/Users/abelbarbosa/Documents/workspace/WebConFuturo/target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>/Users/abelbarbosa/Documents/workspace/WebConFuturo/src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>/Users/abelbarbosa/Documents/workspace/WebConFuturo/src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>/Users/abelbarbosa/Documents/workspace/WebConFuturo/target</directory>
    <finalName>WebConFuturo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.6</source>
              <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.6</source>
              <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-war</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/Users/abelbarbosa/Documents/workspace/WebConFuturo/target/site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/Users/abelbarbosa/Documents/workspace/WebConFuturo/target/site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>/Users/abelbarbosa/Documents/workspace/WebConFuturo/target/site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>/Users/abelbarbosa/Documents/workspace/WebConFuturo/target/site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

Thank you for your help.

Best regards

Comment: shouldn't you add a maven dependency for appengine? like:   <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the maven appengine plugin. https://code.google.com/p/maven-gae-plugin/

Comment: I added the maven appengine plugin but the error persists. I updated the pom.xml accordingly. Have I done anything wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on the plugin website? You have to run mvn gae:unpack

Comment: "READ-ONLY: This project has been archived."

Comment: 2020 here. Repository got deleted.

Answer (score 4):

In your project build path make sure the AppEngine lib is before your maven lib.
See here how to set it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15314586/1040124

Answer (score 0):

the text got garbled in the comment. so rewriting here, add a dependency for appengine:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

not sure it will solve the problem but tell us the result.

Comment: No unfortunately the problem persists after adding the GAE dependency.