# GAE The selected SDK does not support HRD

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, gwt

When deploying my GWT app to the GAE Via Properties -> Google -> App Engine I select Use Google App Engine.

I get the error "The App Engine SDK '/Users/xxx/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk/1.7.6/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.6.jar' on the project's build path is not valid (SDK location '/Users/xx/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk/1.7.6/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.6.jar' is not a directory) project     Unknown Google App Engine Problem"

And the message "The Selected SDK does not support HRD" - When I select a downloaded version this message goes away.

The App engine sdk is being added by maven:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
        <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
        <version>4.0b3</version>
     </dependency>

com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:jar:4.0b3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:14.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-labs:jar:1.7.6:compile
```

Any Suggestions?

Thanks

EDIT: pom.xml added

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.username.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>project</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>GWTP Basic with GXT</name>
  <description>Basic GWTP application with the GXT library</description>

  <properties>
    <!-- client -->
    <!-- Get the latest GXT release through support 3.0.6... -->
    <gxt.version>3.0.1</gxt.version>
    <gwt.version>2.5.1</gwt.version>
    <gwtp.version>1.0</gwtp.version>
    <gin.version>2.0.0</gin.version>

    <!-- server -->
    <guice.version>3.0</guice.version>

    <!-- testing -->
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <jukito.version>1.1</jukito.version>

    <!-- maven -->
    <gwt-maven-plugin.version>2.5.1</gwt-maven-plugin.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.6</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>2.3.2</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-resources-plugin.version>2.5</maven-resources-plugin.version>
    <maven-processor-plugin.version>2.0.5</maven-processor-plugin.version>
    <maven-build-helper-plugin.version>1.7</maven-build-helper-plugin.version>

    <target.jdk>1.6</target.jdk>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <!-- REST -->
    <resteasy.version>3.0.2.Final</resteasy.version>
    <arcbees.version>1.1.1</arcbees.version>

    <!-- GAE -->
    <gae.version>1.8.3</gae.version>
    <gae.home>${settings.localRepository}/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/${gae.version}/appengine-java-sdk-${gae.version}</gae.home>

    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gae.version}</version>
        </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${target.jdk}</source>
          <target>${target.jdk}</target>
          <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- JUnit Testing - skip *.GwtTest cases -->
      <!-- 'mvn test' - runs the Junit tests -->
      <!-- 'mvn integration-test` - runs GWT test cases -->
      <!-- 'mvn integration-test -P selenium-local` - runs GWT selenium unit test cases -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
          </includes>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*GwtTest.java</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- GWT -->
      <!-- 'mvn gwt:run' - runs development mode -->
      <!-- 'mvn gwt:debug' - runs debug mode -->
      <!-- 'mvn gwt:compile' - compiles gwt -->
      <!-- 'mvn integration-test' - runs the gwt tests (*GwtTest.java) -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <gwtSdkFirstInClasspath>true</gwtSdkFirstInClasspath>
          <strict>true</strict>

          <testTimeOut>180</testTimeOut>
          <includes>**/*GwtTestSuite.java</includes>
          <excludes>**/*GwtTest.java</excludes>
          <mode>htmlunit</mode>

          <extraJvmArgs>-Xss1024K -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M</extraJvmArgs>
          <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>
          <style>${gwt.style}</style>

          <copyWebapp>true</copyWebapp>
          <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>

          <runTarget>TranspoHub.html</runTarget>
          <modules>
            <module>com.tadros.transpohub.TranspoHub</module>
          </modules>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

     </plugins>


  </build>

  <!-- Get the latest release through support, 3.0.6... -->
  <!-- <repositories> -->
    <!-- <repository> -->
      <!-- ~/.m2/settings.xml add <server/> with same id here with login credentials -->
      <!-- <id>sencha-gxt-repository</id> -->
      <!-- <name>Sencha GXT Repository</name> -->
      <!-- Support Subscribers Only: Subscribe to support for -->
      <!-- Latest GPL Support GXT Versions -->
      <!-- <url>https://maven.sencha.com/repo/gxt-support-gpl-release</url> -->
      <!-- Commercial Support GXT Versions -->
      <!-- <url>https://maven.sencha.com/repo/gxt-commercial-release</url> -->
    <!-- </repository> -->
  <!-- </repositories> -->

  <dependencies>
    <!-- GXT -->
    <!-- http://docs.sencha.com/gxt-guides/3/ -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sencha.gxt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gxt</artifactId>
      <version>${gxt.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sencha.gxt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gxt-chart</artifactId>
      <version>${gxt.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Google Web Toolkit -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
      <version>${gwt.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- GWT-Platform -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.gwtplatform</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwtp-mvp-client</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.gwtplatform</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwtp-dispatch-client</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.gwtplatform</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwtp-dispatch-server-guice</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gwtplatform</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwtp-dispatch-rest</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtp.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.gwtplatform</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwtp-dispatch-shared</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtp.version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- DI -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
      <version>${guice.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
      <artifactId>guice-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>${guice.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
      <artifactId>guice-assistedinject</artifactId>
      <version>${guice.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>gin</artifactId>
      <version>${gin.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- OTHER -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
        <version>0.3m</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
        <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
        <version>4.0b3</version>
<!--         <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId> -->
            <!-- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-labs:jar:1.7.6:compile 
mvn dependency:tree
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions> -->
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
            <groupId>com.arcbees</groupId>
            <artifactId>guicy-resteasy</artifactId>
            <version>${arcbees.version}</version>
     </dependency>

        <!-- REST -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-guice</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>    

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jukito</groupId>
      <artifactId>jukito</artifactId>
      <version>${jukito.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
      <version>2.33.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>2.33.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>${gae.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <profiles>
    <!-- run with 'mvn integration-test -P selenium-local' -->
    <profile>
      <id>selenium-local</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <mode>selenium</mode>
              <productionMode>true</productionMode>
              <selenium>localhost:4444/*firefox,localhost:4444/*opera</selenium>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to clean up your maven pom a bit to add appengine differently. You have the following error in your log "**appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.6.jar' is not a directory**"

Similar Query/Solution - [appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.6.jar is not a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721818/appengine-api-1-0-sdk-1-7-6-jar-is-not-a-directory)

Also please go through google documentation for appengine usage with maven [**here**](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven).

Comment: Thank you SSR, I've looked at those links before and have not been able to solve the problem.  I've attached my pom.xml to see if it does need to be cleaned up.

Comment: @user1256378 late reply but running into this suddenly too after an update of the eclipse plugin. not using maven. how did you fix it

Comment: My problem was related to Maven, and the "Java Build Path",  I needed to move the Maven Dependencies to the bottom in the Order and Export.  I'm not sure why this is occurring for you.