# SDK Location is not a directory

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

I am using eclipse Kepler
Google app engine 1.8.8
Maven 3.1

I wanted to start working on my first Google App Engine (GAE) project in Eclipse. As always, I wanted to stick to maven with its great dependency management and WAR deployment. Unfortunately,

I got this error message. [image]

So my question why eclipse cannot find SDK? I dont want to add external sdk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to try out the following:

1. Go to your Eclipse Preferences -> Google -> App Engine. Make sure you are using the App Engine plugin SDK.
2. Go to Java Project -> Properties. In the Order and Export, make sure that the Eclipse app Engine SDK is higher than the one that your Maven repository is pointing too.

Check this out : [How to run maven project on google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107612/how-to-run-maven-project-on-google-app-engine/15314586#15314586)

Comment: When I go through 1st step I got auto select Maven path. and I have only maven repo in build path. should I have to add external GAE SDK path in GPE?

Comment: Yes. Please add that. Use that in the project and try out.